# Checking input and email field

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, email

I've written this as part of my contact form on my website. It checks to see if required inputs are empty, if so adds a red warning color and text. It also checks the email field for a properly formatted email.

This code works 100%, but somehow I feel like I'm repeating myself and I am not sure how to eliminate the repetition. Most importantly I am not sure how to reference nested "this". What I mean is if my input is jQuery (this) and then I use traversing to get to its parent div.

How can I reference that DIV over and over again, without having to traverse over and over again?

```
//Check current language and prepare warning text
var current_language = jQuery('html').attr('lang');

if (current_language == 'en-CA') {
    var empty_field_message = 'This field is required.';
    var invalid_email = 'This email address seems invalid.';
}
else {
    var empty_field_message = 'Ce champ est requis.';
    var invalid_email = 'L\'adresse email semble invalide.';
}

//Email validation script
function validateEmail($email) {
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

    if( !emailReg.test( $email ) ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


//Fire on all input elements of the form
jQuery( ':input' ).on( 'focus', function() {
    //Add a highlight color to div containing the currently active form element
    jQuery(this).closest( '.frm-holder' ).addClass( 'frm-field-focus' );
}).on('blur', function() {

    //Remove the highlight once user moves off the input
    jQuery(this).closest( '.frm-holder' ).removeClass( 'frm-field-focus' );

    //Check if field was required
    if ( jQuery(this).hasClass('wpcf7-validates-as-required') ) {

        //Check if it was empty
        if ( !jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val()) ) {

            //Add a red background to the wrapping DIV
            jQuery(this).closest( '.frm-holder' ).addClass( 'frm-field-required' );

            //Remove any other warning spans and put in empty field warning
            jQuery(this).siblings( 'span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip' ).remove();
            jQuery(this).after('<span class="wpcf7-not-valid-tip" role="alert">' + empty_field_message + '</span>');

        }
        //If it wasn't empty
        else {

            //Check if it's an email field
            if ( jQuery(this).attr('type') == 'email') {
                //If email is invalid
                if( !validateEmail( jQuery(this).val() ) ) { 
                    //Remove any other warning spans
                    jQuery(this).siblings( 'span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip' ).remove();

                    //Check if wrapping DIV does not have red background
                    if ( !jQuery(this).closest( '.frm-holder' ).hasClass( 'frm-field-required' ) ) {
                        //Add wrapping DIV red background
                        jQuery(this).closest( '.frm-holder' ).addClass( 'frm-field-required' );
                    }

                    //Add new warning span
                    jQuery(this).after('<span class="wpcf7-not-valid-tip" role="alert">' + invalid_email + '</span>');
                }
                //If email is valid
                else {
                    //Remove wrapping DIV red background
                    jQuery(this).closest( '.frm-holder' ).removeClass( 'frm-field-required' );
                    //Remove warning span
                    jQuery(this).siblings( 'span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip' ).remove();
                }
            }
            //If not email field
            else {

                //Check if wrapping DIV has red background
                if ( jQuery(this).closest( '.frm-holder' ).hasClass( 'frm-field-required' ) ) {

                    //Remove wrapping DIV red background
                    jQuery(this).closest( '.frm-holder' ).removeClass( 'frm-field-required' );

                    //Check if warning span exists
                    if ( jQuery(this).siblings( jQuery('span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip').length ) ) {

                        //Remove warning span
                        jQuery(this).siblings( 'span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip' ).remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: You should probably have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: @Josay thank you for that link. After reading through it, there still doesn't seem to be 100% agreement on what's best to implemennt. Seems like every solution has some upside and downsides. I decided to change my code to this, what do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a once over:

I would do the languages like this:

```
var translations = {
  'en-CA' : {
    emptyFieldMessage: 'This field is required.',
    invalidEmail     : 'This email address seems invalid.'
  },
  'fr-CA' : {
    emptyFieldMessage: 'Ce champ est requis.',
    invalidEmail     : 'L\'adresse email semble invalide.'    
  }
}

var messages = translations[ jQuery('html').attr('lang') ];
```

Then you can access `emptyFieldMessage` as `messages.emptyFieldMessage`

This:

```
if( !emailReg.test( $email ) ) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

can be this because you are evaluating a boolean to return a boolean:

```
return emailReg.test( $email );
```

The `//If not email field` `else` block can be reduced to:

```
//If not email field
else {
  //Remove wrapping DIV red background
  jQuery(this).closest( '.frm-holder' ).removeClass( 'frm-field-required' );
  //Remove warning span
  jQuery(this).siblings( 'span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip' ).remove();
}
```

if you are going to remove a class, dont check for it's existence, just call `removeClass`, it will silently do nothing if the class was not there in the first place. The same goes for `remove()`, just call it, dont check prior.

This is most likely [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address) as per Josay:

```
var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
```

Very important, create a `var $this = jQuery(this);` instead of calling over and over again `jQuery(this)`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I've updated my code. I wasn't aware that removeClass and remove won't do any damage if just fired. That cleaned up a lot of the code. What about addClass, I have one more check in my code to make sure it doesn't keep adding the same class over and over again. Is that necessary?

Comment: @Amir Not needed indeed.